# Does paypal provide something like stripe.js

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments

stripe.js allows to associate a customer id with credit card. So, I don't need to store credit card and can still make payments multiple time for the same customer without asking for credit card details again.

Is there a similar flow for Paypal?

Answer (score 1):

PayPals new REST API allows you to [store a credit card in the vault](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#store-a-credit-card), which will assign an id/token to it.  You can then use that credit card token in future payments.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Finn's answer:

The advantage of Stripe.js is that there's no need for you to ever handle the customer's Credit Card info - it gets sent straight to Stripe's servers and never touches yours.

From the link he provided, it looks like you first have to process the credit card info on your severs, then send it to PayPal - although I suppose you could use Javascript to get the credit card info out of a form, create a POST request using jQuery (or similar) then retrieve the credit card info from the response and put that in the form - much like you [have to do with Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js)